# Blender Game Engine ноды, влияние тумана

Tags: разработка-игр, blender

В игре есть материал с нодами которые добавляют посинение на высоте < 0 по Z но при этом посинении не действует туман (Mist) включенный в World меню. На верхнюю (не задетую нодами) он действует. Вопрос: как включить влияние тумана на синий цвет в Color2 в Mix?

[image: ноды]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы наверно, подумали, что туман накладывается поверх изображения в виде полупрозрачной маски, но это не так, на самом деле туман применяется к материалу.

И поскольку, туман влияет на материал, а не на обычный цвет, то предлагается смешать 2 материала,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а если необходимо убрать затенение, можно нажать у материала галочку **shadeless**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про то как туман работатет я знал, но что-то не подумал про смешивание материалов.